# What is the syntax for assigning a feature attribute value to a variable in the QGIS Advanced Python Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

Using the QGIS Advanced Python Field Calculator, I am able to assign the new field a value from a feature an existing field using `value = <Attribute_1>`.  I run into a problem when I am using more complex code like the following used to calculate the absolute differences in azimuths:

```
diff = <Az_1> - <Az_2>
absDiff = abs(diff)

if absDiff == 180:
    value = absDiff
elif absDiff < 180:
    value = diff
elif <Az_1> > <Az_2>:
    value = absDiff - 360
else:
    value = 360 - absDiff
```

When I run the code through a compile and substitute the `Az_1` and `Az_2` variables with integers, the code works, yet I get the following error when executing the model the code is a part of in QGIS:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: At least one of  `<Az_1>` values must be `NULL`. Check  `<Az_1>` values in Attribute Table.

Comment: What do you mean by "running the code through a compile"?

Comment: Compiler.  Thank you for the help, I will check for null values.

Comment: I removed Null values by using the Extract by Expression algorithm to extract features where "Az_1 IS NOT NULL AND Az_2 IS NOT NULL" into a new temporary layer, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Use "Az_1 IS NOT NULL OR Az_2 IS NOT NULL" to extracte features into a temporary layer, then try again. This may work.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following statement which checks for a 'none' value, and if detected, reassigns it a value of 181. Since 181 is not a valid difference between two azimuths, it can then be deleted using the Extract by Value algorithm.  If the value of Az_1 and Az_2 are both numbers, the program calls a function which will run the azimuth calculation code described in the original post.

```
if Az_1 is None:
    value = 181
elif AZ_2 is None:
    value = 181
else:
    value = abs(AzimuthDifference())
```